# Trigger "instead of delete", can it work?

Tags: sql, triggers

```
ALTER Trigger tr_sal On salaries
Instead of delete 
AS  
  declare @id int
  set @id=(select id_teacher from deleted)
  if  @id in (select ID_teacher from techers)
  BEGIN 
    print 'not able !!'
  END
  ELSE
  BEGIN
    delete from salaries where id_teacher=@id
  END

  delete from salaries
  where id_teacher=???--(write id)
```

What I wanted to do:

If id is of teacher, you can not delete his/her salary, else you can delete.

I run this and get both:

1. Not able to delete without allowance!!
2. (1 row(s) affected)

Is my trigger working or not?

Answer (score 0):

You have two separate `DELETE` statements. The first one is probably not executing, but the second (the one outside any BEGIN/END pair) is, and that's what's deleting the row.

Remove the second `delete from salaries` completely, along with the `where` on the next line.

Answer (score 0):

Your trigger is poorly designed. Never **under any circumstances** assume only one record in the deleted (or instered) pseudotable. You should never set the value of an id to a scalar variable. If 20 records were deleted, then only one is going to be affected by the rest of the code of the trigger. Triggers are set-based in SQL Server, they do not run row by row. This is the first thing you need to fix. And do not put print statements in a trigger, they are useless. You also need to understand how the trigger would work if some of the records should be deleted and others should not.

Now to know whether your trigger is working you need to unit test.

Write a delete statment to delete from the table. Make sure it deletes multiple records and that you know from a select statment exactly which records you expect to delete and which you do not.
Run it
Check to see if the action you expected from the trigger happened and if the records were or were not deleted.

You should know how to do this and not have to go to the Internet to figure out if your own code worked.

Your logic is a bit odd, usually you don't want to delete a parent record if the child record exists not the other way around (which is what an FK does). You need to delete the child records first to be able to delete the parent (unless you use cascade delete which is a horrible practice even then you might run into this problem and you should test your trigger to see what happens when you delete a teacher), so your trigger is likely to cause problems in maintaining the data if it did what you intended.